# Error with sass and Vue 3 - Cannot find module 'sass'

Tags: sass, vuejs3

I'm reciving this error

> Failed to compile. ./node_modules/primeflex/src/_variables.scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-3-3!./node_modules/primeflex/src/_variables.scss)
> Module Error (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): Cannot
> find module 'sass' Require stack:
>
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/utils.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
> - /Users/agustinguerra/Proyectar/proyectos/dacal/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js

when i import the `scss` from `primeflex`

```
import 'primeflex/src/_variables.scss';
import 'primeflex/src/_grid.scss';
import 'primeflex/src/_formlayout.scss';
import 'primeflex/src/_display.scss';
import 'primeflex/src/_text.scss';
import 'primeflex/src/flexbox/_flexbox.scss';
import 'primeflex/src/_spacing.scss';
import 'primeflex/src/_elevation.scss';
```

this is my `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "dacal",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "scss": "sass --watch scss -o css"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@vueform/multiselect": "^1.4.0",
        "@vueform/slider": "^1.0.5",
        "@vueform/toggle": "^1.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "mdb-vue-ui-kit": "*",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
        "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
        "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
        "primevue": "^3.4.0",
        "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
        "vue": "^3.0.11",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
        "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.1.2",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.1.2",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^3.3.1",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.13",
        "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
        "webpack": "^4.46.0"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead"
    ]
}
```

> I tried:

-$ npm install sass

-$ npm install -D sass-loader@^10 sass

-$ npm rebuild sass

-$ npm rebuild sass-loader

nothing worked.

some suggestion?

thaks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try using**

```
npm install sass-loader@10 node-sass --save-dev
```